# PCRE Regular Expression with NOT Operation

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use something equivalent to a NOT operation in a regular expression so as to match the string only if it does NOT contain a certain character in a given position?

I see the meta characters say ^ can mean "negate a class" but I am having trouble finding examples of its use.  And that particular character is ambiguous with the start of a string so its a bit confusing as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 'foo[^b]ar'
```

Will match anything starts with `foo` and ends with `ar` but `foobar`. So it negates the `[^b]` class, which can be a list of characters too (and using ranges is accepted like: `[^b-d]` which skips b, c, d).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they're called **lookahead negative assertions**
*e.g.* `some_re(?!not_on_my_watch)`

You might also be interested in:

- *lookbehind* negative assertions
  *e.g.* `(?<!not_even_before_my_watch)`
- and negative character classes `[^\d\sa-z]`

You might also want to check the relative [pcre/php documentation for assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).
To see if you find some other interesting ones.

**PLEASE NOTE:** Negative assertions <strike>may</strike> *will* match against your will. They will match positions in the string you didn't think of.

Be prepared for:

- a lot of trial and error,
- fully understanding how to use the greedyness modifier, (`.*?`)
- starting to consider weird constructs like [once-only subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.onlyonce.php) and [conditional subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php)

Answer (score 5):

The regex for a certain character (for example `x`) not being in a *particular* position (say position 5) is:

```
^.{4}[^x]
```

The regex for a certain character (for example `x`) not being *anywhere* is:

```
^(?!.*x)
```